# Какой инструмент использовать для оптимизации JS и удалении неиспользуемого кода

Tags: javascript, php, compression

**Вводная**:
Проверяя сайт инструментом Lighthouse столкнулся с одинаковой рекомендацией для мобилы и десктопа по удалению неиспользуемого JS-кода. Причём указания у скриптов инструкции defer, не дало существенного влияния на показатель производительности, который к тому же постоянно скачет из раза в раз.

**Контекст**:
На сайте (сервер на php), при запросе страницы формируется единый файл js, который по сути является склейкой всех скриптов для конкретной страницы. Для разных типов страниц свой склееный js-файл. Минимизации там нет, потому что в прошлом были проблемы с получившимся итоговым файлом, где возникали ошибки или даже пропадал некоторый код. Минимизировал склейку посредством библиотек php. Поэтому минимизацию оставил в прошлом и оставил только склейку.
К слову, библиотеки, типа jquery, jquery-ui хранятся локально на сервере и попадают в склейку.

**Вопрос**:
Есть ли инструменты, которым можно передать список файлов и которые не просто склеют и минимизируют содержимое, но и смогут удалить неиспользуемый код?

**PS**. Пробовал webpack, но он не завёлся как надо и удалял, то что не надо было удалять и к тому же ему видимо нужна другая организация структуры js, а не полностью локальная

Comment: Нужен другой подход к написанию JS, стараться переписать всё на JS, вместо JQ. Webpack конечно хорошо, но это не так, что поставил и готово. К слову, закомментируйте аналитику и пройдите pagespeed ещё раз, скорость сразу поднимется.

Comment: Это тоже пробовал, но как бы аналитика важна, от неё никак не избавиться.
> Нужен другой подход к написанию JS, стараться переписать всё на JS, вместо JQ
Это тоже понятно, но связка уже очень сильная с JQ и рефакторинга на год будет. А мне как раз надо понять, можно ли без рефакторинга, а чисто инструментально решить проблему со сжатием кода

Comment: Никто не говорит удалять аналитику, лишь закомментируйте, сделайте текст, покажите клиенту, верните аналитику обратно, либо объясните, что нагрузка из-за аналитики.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот парочка инструментов которые возможно помогут

- parceljs:  простой инструмент сборки, который автоматически обнаруживает импортированные модули и удаляет неиспользуемый код.
- UglifyJS — набор инструментов для парсера, минификатора, сжатия и улучшения JavaScript.
- Rollup - инструмент для сборки модулей, может работать со списком файлов, встроенные плагины позволяют делать минификацию и tree-shaking

В целом для твоей задачи лучше подойдет Rollup или Parcel из коробки